# Isomorphisms of the tensor product of $\mathcal{A}^N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism, morita-equivalence

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an algebra and define $\mathcal{A}^N:=\mathcal{A}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathcal{A}$.

I need to show that

1. $\mathcal{A}^N\otimes_\mathcal{A} \mathcal{A}^N\cong M_N(\mathcal{A})$
2. $\mathcal{A}^N\otimes_{M_N(\mathcal{A})} \mathcal{A}^N\cong \mathcal{A}$

I tried to find an algebra-isomorphism for 1. but failed. I would expect the conclusion that 1. implies 2., but I am not sure how that really follows.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Include your thoughts and your attempts, even if they failed. Also, focus on one question per post.

Comment: @AnneBauval thanks for your answer. It helps a lot.